# Problems with appending core data into an array in incrementing it

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I am trying to make a simple flash card app using core data and arrays. I am having trouble with getting the labels to print the next element in the array. When the next button is pressed the label will print out the next term, but after that it just stays on that term, is it an issue with saving into core data or am i just incrementing wrong? I am almost positive it is an issue with the fetchData() function, i am just not sure what the specific issue with it is or how to fix it.

```
class saveScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var background: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var termTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var definitionTextField: UITextField!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let card = Card(context: context)
        card.term = termTextField.text
        card.definition = termTextField.text

        if(termTextField.text != "" && definitionTextField.text != ""){
            ad.saveContext()
        }

        termTextField.text = ""
        definitionTextField.text = ""

    }

    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var termLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var definitionLabel: UILabel!

    var fetched = [Card]()
    var fetchedTerm = [String]()
    var fetchedDefinition = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       fetchData()

    }

    func fetchData() {
        do {
            fetched = try context.fetch(Card.fetchRequest())
            for each in fetched {
                termLabel.text = each.term
                definitionLabel.text = each.definition
                fetchedTerm.append(each.term!)
                fetchedDefinition.append(each.definition!)

            }
        } catch {

        }


    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {

        var termIterator = fetchedTerm.makeIterator()
        var nextTerm = termIterator.next()
        termLabel.text = nextTerm

    } 

}
```

Comment: Nope, you are iterating wrong. Your iterator is a local variable of the nextButton action.  Make it a property of your view controller instead. Call makeIterator at the end of your fetchData.

Comment: so the termIterator = fetchedTerm.makeIterator() would just go at the end of the fetch data function? and also how would i declare an empty iterator? i appreciate the help

Comment: No worries. Declare an empty iterator by calling makeIterator on your empty array.  That will be the easiest for you since the type will be inferred for you.  Otherwise, take a peek at this:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/iterator

Comment: it is giving me a "Use of undeclared type 'fetchedTerm'" error, when i use the declaration type alias termIterator = IndexingIterator<fetchedTerm<Array>>

Comment: var termIterator: IndexingIterator<[String]>? = nil  ...  will work for your declaration.  The type of the thing is IndexingIterator<Array<String>>

Comment: that worked, thanks a ton